# How to specialize std::hash<Key>::operator() for user-defined type in unordered containers?

Tags: c++, hash, c++11, unordered-map, unordered-set

To support user-defined key types in `std::unordered_set<Key>` and `std::unordered_map<Key, Value>`
one has to provide `operator==(Key, Key)` and a hash functor:

```
struct X { int id; /* ... */ };
bool operator==(X a, X b) { return a.id == b.id; }

struct MyHash {
  size_t operator()(const X& x) const { return std::hash<int>()(x.id); }
};

std::unordered_set<X, MyHash> s;
```

It would be more convenient to write just `std::unordered_set<X>`
with a *default hash* for type `X`, 
like for types coming along with the compiler and library.
After consulting

- C++ Standard [Draft N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) §20.8.12 [unord.hash] and §17.6.3.4 [hash.requirements],
- [Boost.Unordered](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/unordered.html)
- g++ `include\c++\4.7.0\bits\functional_hash.h`
- VC10 `include\xfunctional`
- various [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647967/how-to-extend-stdtr1hash-for-custom-types)s in Stack Overflow

it seems possible to specialize `std::hash<X>::operator()`:

```
namespace std { // argh!
  template <>
  inline size_t 
  hash<X>::operator()(const X& x) const { return hash<int>()(x.id); } // works for MS VC10, but not for g++
  // or
  // hash<X>::operator()(X x) const { return hash<int>()(x.id); }     // works for g++ 4.7, but not for VC10 
}
```

Given compiler support for C++11 is yet experimental---I did not try Clang---, these are my questions:

1. Is it legal to add such a specialization to namespace `std`? I have mixed feelings about that.
2. Which of the `std::hash<X>::operator()` versions, if any, is compliant with C++11 standard?
3. Is there a portable way to do it?

Comment: With gcc 4.7.2, I had to provide a global `operator==(const Key, const Key)`

Comment: Note that specialization of `std::hash` (unlike other things in `std` namespace) are [discouraged by Google style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#std_hash); take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You are expressly allowed and encouraged to add *specializations* to namespace `std`*. The correct (and basically only) way to add a hash function is this:

```
namespace std {
  template <> struct hash<Foo>
  {
    size_t operator()(const Foo & x) const
    {
      /* your code here, e.g. "return hash<int>()(x.value);" */
    }
  };
}
```

(Other popular specializations that you might consider supporting are `std::less`, `std::equal_to` and `std::swap`.)

<sub>*) as long as one of the involved types is user-defined, I suppose.</sub>

Comment: while this is possible, would you in general recommend doing it this way? I'd prefer instantiation `unorder_map<eltype, hash, equality>` instead, to avoid ruining someone's day with funny ADL business. (**Edit** [Pete Becker's advice on this topic](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/820457-how-have-user-defined-hash-unordered_map))

Comment: @sehe: If you have a hash functor lying around that is default-constructible, perhaps, but why? (Equality is easier, since you'd just implement member-`operator==`.) My general philosophy is that if the function is natural and essentially the only "correct" one (like lexicographic pair comparison), then I add it to `std`. If it's something peculiar (like unordered pair comparison), then I make it specific to a container type.

Comment: Should be `size_t operator()(const Foo & x) const`.

Comment: It works on both compilers when adding a `const` modifier for the method. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I posted my lightweight take on this (which, incidentally, in no way requires a function object; even if you chose to use one, it didn't need to be default constructible, AFAICT)

Comment: @KerrekSB (or anyone else) I don't understand the "template<> struct hash<Foo>". Could you explain what it means and why you're doing this please ? Thx

Comment: @Virus721: That's the syntax for template specialization.

Comment: I am not disagreeing, but where in the standard are we allowed and encouraged to add specializations to std?

Comment: @razeh: all over the place, e.g. `hash`, but also all sorts of traits... `allocator_traits`, `pointer_traits`, `iterator_traits`...

Comment: @Kerrek, I agree, but I was hoping for a chapter and verse reference to a place in the standard.  I found the wording allowing the injection at 17.6.4.2.1 where it says it is not allowed "unless otherwise specified", but I haven't been able to find the "otherwise specified" part amid the 4000+ page specification.

Comment: @razeh [here you can read](http://timepp.github.io/doc/cpp14/namespace.std.html) "A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited.". So this solution is ok.

Comment: This answer seems to have been copied to [https://coderedirect.com/...](https://coderedirect.com/questions/114942/how-to-specialize-stdhashkeyoperator-for-user-defined-type-in-unordered). No credits given.

Answer (score 7):

My bet would be on the Hash template argument for the unordered_map/unorder_set/... classes:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <functional>

struct X 
{
    int x, y;
    std::size_t gethash() const { return (x*39)^y; }
};

typedef std::unordered_set<X, std::size_t(*)(const X&)> Xunset;
typedef std::unordered_set<X, std::function<std::size_t(const X&)> > Xunset2;

int main()
{
    auto hashX = [](const X&x) { return x.gethash(); };

    Xunset  my_set (0, hashX);
    Xunset2 my_set2(0, hashX); // if you prefer a more flexible set typedef
}
```

Of course

- hashX could just as well be a global static function
- in the second case, you could pass that

  - the oldfashioned functor object (`struct Xhasher { size_t operator(const X&) const; };`)
  - `std::hash<X>()`
  - any bind expression satisfying the signature
    -

Comment: I appreciate that you can write something that doesn't have a default constructor, but I always find that requiring each map construction to remember the additional argument is a bit of a burden -- quite a bit too much of a burden for my taste. I'm OK with an explicit template argument, though specialising `std::hash` is still the nicest way out :-)

Comment: *user-defined* types to the rescue :-) More seriously, I hope we'd slap them on the wrists already at the stage where their class contains a `char*`!

Comment: Hmm... do you have an example of how a `hash` specialization interferes via ADL? I mean, it's entirely plausible, but I have a hard time coming up with a problem case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5078/discussion-between-sehe-and-kerrek-sb)

Comment: It's all fun and games until you need a `std::unordered_map<Whatever, Xunset>` and it doesn't work because your `Xunset` hasher type isn't default constructible.

Answer (score 4):

@Kerrek SB has covered 1) and 3).

2) Even though g++ and VC10 declare `std::hash<T>::operator()` with different signatures, both library implementations are Standard compliant.

The Standard does not specify the members of `std::hash<T>`.  It just says that each such specialization must satisfy the same "Hash" requirements needed for the second template argument of `std::unordered_set` and so on.  Namely:

- Hash type `H` is a function object, with at least one argument type `Key`.
- `H` is copy constructible.
- `H` is destructible.
- If `h` is an expression of type `H` or `const H`, and `k` is an expression of a type convertible to (possibly `const`) `Key`, then `h(k)` is a valid expression with type `size_t`.
- If `h` is an expression of type `H` or `const H`, and `u` is an lvalue of type `Key`, then `h(u)` is a valid expression with type `size_t` which does not modify `u`.

Comment: No, neither implementation is standard compliant, since they attempt to specialize `std::hash<X>::operator()` rather than `std::hash<X>` as a whole, and the signature of `std::hash<T>::operator()` is implementation-defined.

Comment: @ildjarn: Clarified - I was talking about the library implementations, not the attempted specializations.  Not sure which exactly the OP meant to ask.