# How to specialize std::hash for type from other library

Tags: c++, hash, stl, unordered-set, stdhash

So the library I use has an enum (say it's named `LibEnum`). I need to have an `std::unordered_set` of `LibEnum`, but I get compilation error that there is no specialized `std::hash` for it. I could easily write it and just return the number of value (first element is 0, second 1 etc), but where exactly I should put this specialization and how should it look like?  I can't modify the library sources.

```
  enum LibEnum { A, B, C, D};
  std::unordered_set <LibEnum> mySet;
  //need std::hash for LibEnum
  //how should it look like?
```

Comment: As you using an `enum` this [document](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/02/closer-to-perfection) describes the extensions to `enum`s introduced in c++11 (just incase you are unware).

Comment: @hmjd interesting read, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specialize std::hash<Key>::operator() for user-defined type in unordered containers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157937/how-to-specialize-stdhashkeyoperator-for-user-defined-type-in-unordered)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just specialise `std::hash` for your type:

```
namespace std {
    template <>
    struct hash<FullyQualified::LibEnum> {
        size_t operator ()(FullyQualified::LibEnum value) const {
            return static_cast<size_t>(value);
        }
    };
}
```

Alternatively, you can define a `hash` type where ever you like and just provide it as the additional template argument when instantiating `std::unordered_map<FooEnum>`:

```
// Anywhere in your code prior to usage:

struct myhash {
    std::size_t operator ()(LibEnum value) const {
        return static_cast<std::size_t>(value);
    }
};

// Usage:

std::unordered_map<LibEnum, T, myhash> some_hash;
```

Neither methods require you to modify the library.