# Can I override std::hash?

Tags: c++, c++11, hashtable, stdhash

I can replace the actual implementation of `std::hash` with my own definition of `std::hash` in C++ 11 ?

I mean from my codebase, without touching the standard library.

I can't see any use for virtual function/polymorphism in this case, so I suppose that I can't alter the definition of std::hash anyway ?

Comment: You can provide a specialization for *your* own types.

Comment: @Xeo yes, I know that, but I was interested in a global change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specialize std::hash<Key>::operator() for user-defined type in unordered containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157937/how-to-specialize-stdhashkeyoperator-for-user-defined-type-in-unordered)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it's okay, and you don't have to modify the standard library in any way, just use template specialization:

```
namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct hash<YourSpecialType>
    {
        // ...
    };
}
```

Comment: @user2485710 Ah, then no. Then you have fork the standard library.

Comment: @user2485710: Global replacement of the hash function doesn't make much if any sense. What would it accomplish?

Comment: @Xeo changing the hash function used by any structure in just one move.

Comment: @user2485710 How do you implement `std::hash` for any arbitrary type in C++? (hint: it doesn't work)

Comment: You can implement type with a different name, like struct HashInt{}, and specify it where use it, e.g unordered_map<int, int, HashInt>

Answer (score 9):

You can specialise hash for specific types.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813965/how-to-specialize-stdhash-for-type-from-other-library) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157937/how-to-specialize-stdhashkeyoperator-for-user-defined-type-in-unordered) e.g. like this

```
namespace std {
  template <> struct hash<Foo>
  {
    size_t operator()(const Foo & x) const
    {
      /* your code here, e.g. "return hash<int>()(x.value);" */
    }
  };
}
```

If you think you can do better than the library implementors for existing versions you are either
1. wrong
or
2. clever

Comment: _3. lazy_ , so I can get a new hash function without writing X new types.

Comment: "X new types"? Just write a myHash function and use that instead, but that's probably not lazy - you will have to read Knuth for hours first to get it right.

Comment: the lazy part was about "writing" indeed :D but thanks for the reference to the creator of Tex and other bozillion of algorithms and books.