# How to specialize std::hash<T> for user defined types?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, unordered-set, hash-function

**The Question**

What is a good specialization of std::hash for use in the third template parameter of std::unordered_map or std::unordered_set for a user defined type for which all member data types already have a good specialization of std::hash?

For this question, I define "good" as simple to implement and understand, reasonably efficient, and unlikely to produce hash table collisions. The definition of good does not include any statements about security.

**The State of What is Google'able**

At the moment, two StackOverflow questions are the first hits for a Google search of "std hash specialization".

The first, [How to specialize std::hash::operator() for user-defined type in unordered containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157937/how-to-specialize-stdhashkeyoperator-for-user-defined-type-in-unordered), addresses whether it is legal to open the std namespace and add template specializations.

The second, [How to specialize std::hash for type from other library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813965/how-to-specialize-stdhash-for-type-from-other-library), essentially addresses that same question.

This leaves the current question. Given that implementations of the C++ Standard Library defined hash functions for primitive types and types in the Standard Library, what is a simple and effective way of specializing std::hash for user defined types? Is there a good way to combine hash functions provided by a Standard Library implementation?

(Edit thanks to dyp.) [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590677/how-do-i-combine-hash-values-in-c0x) on StackOverflow addresses how to combine a *pair* of hash functions.

The other Google results are of no more help.

[This](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/user-defined-hash-functions-for-unordere/231600210?pgno=2) Dr. Dobbs article states that XOR of two satisfactory hashes will produce a new satisfactory hash.

[This](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3333.html) articles seems to speak from knowledge and implies many things but is light on details. It contradicts the Dr. Dobbs article in a brief remark in the first example, saying that using XOR to combine hash functions makes for a weak resulting hash function.

Because XOR applied to any two equal values results in 0, I can see why XOR by itself is weak.

**The Meta Question**

A well reasoned answer explaining why this question is invalid and cannot be answered generally would also be welcome.

Comment: Maybe you should add to the list questions about [combining hashes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2590677)?

Comment: Ah, good catch, I didn't find that one. That might actually be an answer.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure. That answer is for *two* values, I do not know if the quality of the algorithm is good enough when recursively applied to N values. It seems even `tuple` isn't hashable with the standard facilities, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7110301

Comment: We're working on it in the standard, but for now it's tricky. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3980.html has a good approach, but it makes it slightly harder for the compiler to optimize. Hopefully we'll be able to work that out in the next 6 months (sorry, standards are slow) and put something in the next experimental release.

Comment: @dyp I didn't realize that about tuple! I just tried it, and indeed, my compiler barfed, interesting.

Comment: There is a public domain partial implementation of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3980.html here: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/hash_append/blob/master/hash_append.h and lots of example code using it here:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/hash_append  It isn't completely implementable by you, which is why it must be standardized.  However I am using it well enough in a real-world project right now.  It eliminates the combining step, and allows you to choose and easily switch out what hash algorithm is used, even for primitive types.

Comment: Bloomberg has just open-sourced their production quality N3980 implementation: https://github.com/bloomberg/bde/blob/master/groups/bsl/bslh/doc/bslh.txt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Good Hash Function for Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624192/good-hash-function-for-strings)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One easy way is to use `boost::hash` library and [extend it for your type](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/hash/custom.html). It has a nice extension function [`hash_combine`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#boost.hash_combine) (`std::hash` lacks that) that allows easy composition of hashes of individual data members of your structures.

In other words:

1. Overload `boost::hash_value` for your own type.
2. Specialize `std::hash` for your own type and implement it using `boost::hash_value`.

This way you get the best of std and boost worlds, both `std::hash<>` and `boost::hash<>` work for your type.

---

A better way is to use the proposed new hashing infrastructure in [N3980 Types Don't Know #](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3980.html). This infrastructure makes `hash_combine` unnecessary.

Comment: The problem is that the documented algorithm used by `hash_combine` is a very poor one.

Comment: @JamesKanze You could contribute and make it better.

Comment: @JamesKanze I wonder what metrics you use to tell a poor hash combiner from a good one?

Comment: Mathematical analysis.  I don't know of any way of guaranteeing that one is good, but shifting (rather than multiplying by an odd number) means that the initial elements will eventually be shifted out, and have no impact on the hash.

Comment: Boost's 'hash_combine' shifts both right and left, and xor's the result with the initial value, so it won't lose initial values. You generally test hash functions with a program like https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/wiki/SMHasher. I haven't personally tested Boost's function.

Comment: `64.25`, sort of.  (Integer arithmetic doesn't obey quite the same rules as floating point or real.)  What is actually happening is that you are shifting out information from earlier elements out.  To avoid this, the multiplier must be odd.  (I generally use 127, but this has been chosen empirically---other values are probably just as good.  Although smaller values can lead to clustering near the beginning, if the table is very large, and the number of elements very small.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Is not `(seed << 6) + (seed >> 2)` essentially `seed * 64.25`?

Answer (score 3):

First, the Dr. Dobbs article which says that XOR of two
satisfactory hashes will produce a satisfactory hash is simply
wrong.  This is a good recipe for poor hashes.  In general, to
create a good hash, you start by decomposing your object into
subobjects, each of which there exists a good hash, and
combining the hashs.  One simple way of doing this is something
like:

```
class HashAccumulator
{
    size_t myValue;
public:
    HashAccumulator() : myValue( 2166136261U ) {}
    template <typename T>
    HashAccumulator& operator+=( T const& nextValue )
    {
        myValue = 127U * myValue + std::hash<T>( nextHashValue );
    }
    HashAccumulator operator+( T const& nextHashValue ) const
    {
        HashAccumulator results( *this );
        results += nextHashValue;
        return results;
    }
};
```

(This has been designed so that you can use `std::accumulate` if
you have a sequence of values.)

Of course, this supposed that all of the subtypes have good
implementations of `std::hash`.  For the basics types and
strings, this is a given; for your own types, just apply the
above rule recursively, specializing `std::hash` to use the
`HashAccumulator` on its subtypes.  For a standard container of
a basic type, it's a bit trickier, because you're not (formally,
at least) allowed to specialize a standard template on a type
from the standard library; you'll probably have to create
a class which uses of `HashAccumulator` directly, and explicitly
specify that if you need a hash of such a container.

Comment: See this answer to a related question for why XOR  is not a good way of combining hashes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27952689/545127

Answer (score 2):

Until we get a library in the standard to help with this:

1. Download a modern hasher, like SpookyHash: http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/spooky.html.
2. In the definition of `std::hash<YourType>`, create a `SpookyHash` instance, and `Init` it. Note that picking a random number at either process startup or `std::hash` construction, and using that as the initialization will [make it slightly harder to DoS your program, but doesn't fix the problem](http://emboss.github.io/blog/2012/12/14/breaking-murmur-hash-flooding-dos-reloaded/).
3. Take each field in your structure that contributes to `operator==` ("salient field"), and feed it into `SpookyHash::Update`.

   - Beware types like `double`: they have 2 representations as `char[]` that compare `==`: `-0.0` and `0.0`. Also beware types that have padding. On most machines, `int` doesn't, but it's hard to tell if a `struct` will. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3980.html#is_contiguously_hashable discusses this.
   - If you have sub-structures, you'll get a faster, higher-quality hash value from recursively feeding their fields into the same `SpookyHash` instance. However, this requires adding a method to those structures or manually extracting the salient fields: if you can't do this, it's acceptable to just feed their `std::hash<>` value into the top-level `SpookyHash` instance.
4. Return the output of `SpookyHash::Final` from `std::hash<YourType>`.

Comment: Bloomberg has open-sourced their production quality N3980 implementation: https://github.com/bloomberg/bde/blob/master/groups/bsl/bslh/doc/bslh.txt The SpookyHash implementation is found here: https://github.com/bloomberg/bde/blob/master/groups/bsl/bslh/bslh_spookyhashalgorithm.h

Answer (score 2):

Your operation [is required](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) to

- Return a value of type `size_t`
- Be consistent with the `==` operator.
- Have a low probability of a hash collision for unequal values.

There is no explicit requirement that the hash values are evenly distributed over the range of `size_t` integers. [`cppreference.com` notes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) that

> some implementations [of the standard library] use trivial (identity) hash functions which map an integer to itself

Avoiding hash collisions coupled with that weakness means that a specialization of `std::hash` for your types should **never** simply use a (fast) bitwise XOR (`^`) to combine the sub hashses of your data-members. Consider this example:

```
 struct Point {
    uint8_t x;
    uint8_t y;
 };

 namespace std {
    template<>
    struct hash< Point > {
       size_t operator()(const Point &p) const {
          return hash< uint8_t >(p.x) ^ hash< uint8_t >(p.y);
       }
    };
 }
```

The hashes of `p.x` will be in the range [0,255], and so will the hashes of `p.y`. Therefore the hashes of a `Point` will also be in the range [0,255], with 256 (=2^8) possible values. There are 256*256  (=2^16) unique `Point` objects (a `std::size_t` will typically support 2^32 or 2^64 values). So the probability of a hash collision for a *good* hashing function should be approximately 2^(-16). Our function gives the probability of a hash collision of just under 2^(-8). This is terrible: our hash provides only 8 bits of information, but a good hash should provide 16 bits of information.

If the hashing functions of your data-members provide only hash values in the low parts of the `std::size_t` range, you must "shift" the bits of the component hash before combining them, so they each contribute independent bits of information. Doing a left-wise shift looks simple

```
       return (hash< uint8_t >(p.x) << 8) ^ hash< uint8_t >(p.y);
```

but that will *discard* information (due to overflow) if the implementation of `hash< uint8_t >` (in this case) attempts to spread the hash-code values over the `std::size_t` range.

Accumulating component hash-code values using a multiply-by-prime-and-add method, as [typically done in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/best-implementation-for-hashcode-method), probably works better in general:

```
 namespace std {
    template<>
    struct hash< Point > {
       size_t operator()(const Point &p) const {
          const size_t prime = 257;
          size_t h {hash< uint8_t >(p.x)};
          h = h * prime + hash< uint8_t >(p.y);
          return h;
       }
    };
 }
```