# use boost::boyer_moore with boost::gil

Tags: c++, boost, boost-gil, boyer-moore

I want to search for a small image from a large one, my algorithm is:

1. search for the first line
2. if first line matches, then compare the rest

I want to use boost::algorithm::boyer_moore to do the line searching, it works fine with std::string:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "boost/algorithm/searching/boyer_moore.hpp"
using namespace boost::algorithm;

int main() {
    string s;

    boyer_moore<string::iterator> bm(s.begin(), s.end()); // it compiles
}
```

the code compiles, but this one not:

```
#include "boost/mpl/vector.hpp"
using namespace boost;
#include "boost/gil/gil_all.hpp"
using namespace boost::gil;

#include "boost/algorithm/searching/boyer_moore.hpp"
using namespace boost::algorithm;

int main() {
    typedef rgba8_image_t image_t;
    typedef image_t::view_t view_t;

    view_t vw;

    boyer_moore<view_t::x_iterator> bm(vw.row_begin(0), vw.row_end(0)); // compile error
}
```

Both of them are iterators, what's wrong with the second one?

Thanks.

Comment: It's highly unusual to distort includes by doing `using namespace` before including them, especially so with TMP-heavy libraries (because they will often rely on ADL for name lookups)

Comment: By the way, the tag [tag:gil] is not related to Boost.GIL. The tag you want is [tag:boost-gil]. You should change it in order to maximize the probability of your question reaching an expert in the library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://www.boost.org/libs/algorithm/doc/html/algorithm/Searching.html#the_boost_algorithm_library.Searching.BoyerMoore.customization_points) the algorithm uses an auxiliary data structure called `skip_table`. By default (when the `value_type` of the iterator is not a char or unsigned char) this table uses a `tr1::unordered_map`, and this requires that `gil::pixel` be hash-able. So you have two options: you either change the default skip_table by specializing [`BM_traits`](http://www.boost.org/boost/algorithm/searching/detail/bm_traits.hpp) for your iterator (this is sadly undocumented), or you make `gil::pixel` hash-able. For the latter you can create a `std::size_t hash_value(pixel<ChannelValue,Layout> const& val)` inside the `namespace boost::gil`. The following [compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3525a7bedac3409) with g++ 4.9.0 and Visual Studio 2013 (and does nothing):

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp> //ADDED
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/gil_all.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/searching/boyer_moore.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::gil;
using namespace boost::algorithm;

namespace boost {
    namespace gil
    {
        template <typename ChannelValue, typename Layout>
        std::size_t hash_value(pixel<ChannelValue, Layout> const& b)
        {
            std::size_t seed = 0;
            for (int c = 0; c<num_channels<pixel<ChannelValue, Layout> >::value; ++c)
                hash_combine(seed, b[c]);
            return seed;
        }
    }
}

namespace std { //ADDED
    template <typename ChannelValue, typename Layout>
    struct hash<boost::gil::pixel<ChannelValue,Layout> > {
        size_t operator ()(boost::gil::pixel<ChannelValue, Layout> const& value) const {
            return hash_value(value);
        }
    };
}

int main() {
    typedef rgba8_image_t image_t;
    typedef image_t::view_t view_t;

    view_t vw;

    boyer_moore<view_t::x_iterator> bm(vw.row_begin(0), vw.row_end(0)); // compile error
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the code still not compile with vs2010, here's the output: 
[link](http://pastebin.com/aS5NWUss)

Comment: Following [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813965/how-to-specialize-stdhash-for-type-from-other-library) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24362641/2417774) I have edited the code. It now also compiles with vs2013, hope it also works for you.

Comment: Works for vs2013. Thanks.