# Clang compiling error on 'std::hash<unsigned long>'

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, stdhash

I am trying to compile a project on my mac, which is originally written on linux. It went smoothly on archlinux but has a lot of errors on mac. Especially, I'm very confused with this error message:

```
In file included from /Users/STW/Documents/neuroblaze/nb/tagged_index/tagged_index.t.hpp:4:
/Users/STW/Documents/neuroblaze/nb/tagged_index/tagged_index.hpp:425:26: error: 
      implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::hash<unsigned long>'
  ::std::hash<IndexType> hasher;
                         ^
```

And here is the relevant code:(tagged_index.hpp)

```
namespace std {
/**
 * tagged_index can be hashed. Just forwards the hash to the contained type.
 *
 * @ingroup TaggedIndex
 */
template <typename UniquenessTag, typename IndexType,
          typename ConstructorFunction>
struct hash<tsb::tagged_index<UniquenessTag, IndexType, ConstructorFunction>> {
  using value_type =
      tsb::tagged_index<UniquenessTag, IndexType, ConstructorFunction>;
  ::std::hash<IndexType> hasher;
  size_t operator()(const value_type& l) const { return hasher(l); }
};

/**
 * tagged_offset can be hashed. Just forwards the hash to the contained type.
 *
 * @ingroup TaggedOffset
 */
template <typename UniquenessTag, typename IndexType,
          typename ConstructorFunction>
struct hash<tsb::tagged_offset<UniquenessTag, IndexType, ConstructorFunction>> {
  using value_type =
      tsb::tagged_offset<UniquenessTag, IndexType, ConstructorFunction>;
  ::std::hash<IndexType> hasher;
  size_t operator()(const value_type& l) const { return hasher(l); }
};

} // end namespace std
```

I have included functional in this hpp file.

Comment: You are not allowed to add stuff to `namespace std`.

Comment: Actually it's not my code. And it works just perfect fine on archlinux. Weird.

Comment: @n.m. Except specializations of templates, such as [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8157967/865874).

Comment: What is your version of clang?

Comment: @C.R. clang 3.3 and I've enable c++11 support

Comment: @NothingMore: Are you using `libstdc++` or `libc++`?

Comment: @C.R.:I think it's libc++ at present

Comment: @rodrigo: you're right, my apologies.

Comment: Does tagged_index.hpp `#include <functional>`? Clearly this isn't the complete code, because `tsb::tagged_index` isn't defined, please show the relevant code needed to reproduce the error.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, Yes, functional is defined in tagged_index.hpp.

Answer (score 1):

Are you also including "memory"? I just found what may be a bug in Clang's standard library code.

It has the following definition of hash:

```
template <class _Tp> struct hash;
```

This is not the same as the one in __functional_base:

```
template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY hash;
```

This may violate the ODR, depending on how _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY is defined. All the specializations for hash<> of integer types use that symbol, so possibly the redefinition is invalidating them.

I found that including functional after memory gets better results than including memory after functional.