# How do I specialize a template typename being using as a function parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a simple question so as you can see I have a hash function that returns a long and takes in a K key. This K is a typename in my template class HashTable, my hash function is not all-type encompassing so I need to do function overloading on my function hashfct based on what type K is. How do I specialize the K key if it is a parameter of the function hashfct? In other words, what is the syntax for specializing K key in this specific case where it is a function parameter?

```
template <typename K, V> class HashTable
{
//Code goes here...
}

long hashfct(K key)
{
//Code goes here...
}
```

Comment: When you call `hashfct(key)` the , the correct overload for `K` is automatically selected according to the type of `key`. Any error you have encountered so far?

Comment: @KaenbyouRin I guess I phrased the question wrong but I want specialize the K key so that the overload is only called for example when key is of char type but not any other type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization):

```cpp
template <typename KeyType>
long hashfct(KeyType key) = delete;

template <>
long hashfct<char>(char key) {
    return key;
}

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    char c = 'a';
    //hashfct(a);   //Compile error: hashfct<int>(int) is deleted
    hashfct(c);     //Ok, calls hashfct<char>(char)
    return 0;
}
```

---

As a side note, you can use or specialize [`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) (for specializing `std::hash` see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8157937/9171697)).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Greatly appreciated! I should of realized I could of just done that lol.