# unordered_map with a set<T> as key

Tags: c++, hash, set, unordered-map

I want to create an unordered map using set. but this error apear "error: static assertion failed: hash function must be invocable with an argument of key type|"
can anyone write hasher code?

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe.  There is no `std::hash` specialization for `std::set`.  You need to provide your own hasher

Comment: @NathanOliver how?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157937/how-to-specialize-stdhashkeyoperator-for-user-defined-type-in-unordered